# Inverse of the coupon collectors problem

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory

I believe this problem may be similar to the reverse of the coupon
collectors problem. But I'm not quiet sure.

Given $K$ empty buckets and $N$ balls where $N >= K$.

Then given that a round is defined as initially all the buckets being emptied and then uniformly selecting $N$ buckets and placing one ball in them.

If all of the buckets have at least ***one*** ball the game ends, otherwise another round is attempted.

---

**The Question:** Is there an expression in terms of $K$ and $N$ that can determine the *expected* number of rounds in order to get at least one ball in each of the buckets so as to end the *game*?

Comment: So if in round 1 there still at least 1 empty buckets, i.e. the game has not end and need another round, will the buckets being emptied before placing the second round balls? If yes then the number of rounds needed is just a geometric random variable (you just need to calculate the ending probability of a round). If no then we need slightly more work on it.

Comment: @BGM the buckets are empty at the start of each round - so it does become coupon collectors. Though you've raised an interesting question, if the buckets are not emptied at the end of each round and $N < K$, then what is the expected number of rounds for all the buckets to be filled.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your description, just not sure why the answer is independent of $n$. Do you mean in each round, you are putting $n$ balls one-by-one independently, uniformly over $k$ buckets? The number of balls in each bucket will jointly follows a multinomial distribution and you can calculate the probability of at least 1 empty bucket by inclusion-exclusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When just one bucket is empty, $\Bbb P$(it gets filled) $=\frac1{K}$, and the time taken to get it has a geometric distribution with parameter $\frac1{K}$, which means that the expected number of rounds to fill it is its reciprocal, $\frac{K}1$

Similarly, with two buckets empty, $\Bbb P$(one of them gets filled) $=\frac2{K}$ with corresponding number of rounds needed = $\frac{K}2$

Proceeding similarly, we get $\Bbb E[X] = \frac{K}1 + \frac{K}2 + .... \frac{K}{K}$ $$= \sum_{i=1}^K \frac{K}{i}$$

Thus the result is just the expected number of rounds for the coupon collector's problem.

Comment: I understand now, so it simply devolves to the coupon collectors problem - thank-you for that explanation.

Comment: You're welcome !